# OpenIOC terms and attributes

Tags: ioc

How to map URL IOCs in the [OpenIOC](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830054009/http://openioc.org/resources/An_Introduction_to_OpenIOC.pdf) domain? I thought Network/URI would be the more appropriate term but then I saw an open source project mapping from Network/URI in OpenIOC to URI in MISP and from Network/String in OpenIOC to URL in MISP, I'm not so sure.

What is the meaning of the "type" attribute? For example, regarding the difference between "mir" type (which I've seen used for PortItems) and "network" type (which I've seen used for Network).

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X online?" are off-topic.

Comment: I have reformatted the rest of your question that is on-topic.

Comment: BTW: the wayback machine is your friend: https://web.archive.org/web/20170830054009/http://openioc.org/resources/An_Introduction_to_OpenIOC.pdf